# Crear varias etiquetas con iTextSharp en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo un modulo de embarque para un programa, en el que tienen que ingresar un numero de pedido y cuantas cajas y bolsas se van a enviar en dicho pedido, lo que quiero es que despues de que por ejemplo escriba que el pedido tiene tres cajas , al hacer clic en guardar me haga  tres etiquetas , todas con la misma informacion solo variando con el clasico  "1 de 3" , "2 de 3"
Crear un pdf no es problema , ya lo puedo hacer con Itextsharp, pero no se como " repetir" las hojas segun lo que se pida, si alguien me pudiera dar una idea de como intentarlo pues estoy algo perdido, no necesito codigo, solo ideas , gracias de antemano

Comment: De hecho necesitas codigo, agrega el codigo que usas para generar tu pdf y en base a eso se podrian sugerir cambios o mejoras para que consigas lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando te escriban que el pedido tiene tres cajas tienes que hacer un bucle:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int numeroBultos = 3;
        for (int bulto = 1; bulto <= numeroBultos; bulto++)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Bulto {0} de {1}", bulto, numeroBultos));
            }
    }
}
```

Dentro del bucle (donde yo he puesto que se escriba algo en la consola) puedes hacer 2 cosas:

- Generas un pdf por cada iteración (no te lo aconsejo)
- Generas una página de un pdf que habrás inicializado antes. Esta es la opción más lógica y la que yo te recomendaría.

El código anterior puedes probarlo en [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), con tan sólo copiarlo de aquí, pegarlo en esa web y haciendo *click* en el icono de Run.